# Refresh Control With Hidden Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, uirefreshcontrol

Let me start by saying I have implemented Refresh Control throughout the application I'm working on and understand how it works when used inside a navigation controller with a visible navigation bar. Specifically, my question here is how to use it when the navigation bar is hidden. I have a view controller that is the root view controller (not sure that matters) of a navigation controller and in the `viewWillAppear` hook, I am hiding the navigation bar. The refresh control functionality is working when the user pulls down but you can't see the indicator at all. Any good solutions for solving this problem?

Here is the code that adds the refresh control to the scrollview subclass:

```
self.refreshDelegate = delegate
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.refreshControl?.tintColor = .white
self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(triggerRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
```

Comment: Your Question is when navigation is hidden that time refresh control is disappear or when the navigation bar is visible that time refresh control is disappear?

Comment: When the navigation bar is hidden, the refresh control is also hidden

Comment: where you used it with scrollView or tableView or where ?

Comment: It's a UIScrollView

Comment: Here  in my sample project its working !! not hiding !! Where you create instance of RefreshhControll !

Comment: Can you post the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, looks like an iOS bug.

Solution i found:

1. Set navigation bar hidden **first**:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

2. **After** set refresh control to your scroll:

```
scrollView.refreshControl = yourRefresh
```

So, order is important. With this solution refresh control is visible while navigation bar is hidden.

Comment: Looks like it's still an issue in 2023 with iOS 16. Using SwiftUI and I had to use this order:
`.navigationTitle("title")`, `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)` and `.refreshable { ... }`. Moving `.refreshable` before the two other would hide the refresh control :(